# How to read string data and only get numbers out of it and store it in List

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am getting info about airport and all the runways that belong to that airport. Each runway has 2 numbers on each end. The numbers look like 22R, 27L, 10C, etc.

I want to only extract the numbers and store it in a dynamic list. Then, I will loop through this new dynamic list and subtract each number from the wind in degrees.

For now,  the numbers on the runway are string type, I want to only get numbers, like 22, 27, 10 etc.

Should I use regex, if yes, how can I do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using ASP.NET Core C# and Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are :

```
List<string> stringNums = new List<string>
{
    "22R",
    "27L",
    "10C"
};

List<string> nums = stringNums
    .Select(num => Regex.Match(num, @"\d+").Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I chained ConvertAll(int.Parse) to the end of the ToList();.

Comment: This made the List into an int type. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way I've found to strip out everything from a string but numbers is:

```
new string(input.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

To run all items in a list through that:

```
list.Select(x => new string(x.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()));
```

Comment: For reference, this method is ~10x faster than regex: https://dotnetfiddle.net/n7LOZt